# How do I have image ignore responsiveness until screen width is met?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 project where whenever I minimize the screen a little bit, the image goes underneath the text column. How can I have it where when I minimize the screen it just clips out the image and doesn't send it to the bottom until the screen reaches a certain width? Right now it sends the image to the bottom way too soon.

```
 <div class="container-xs" style="border:2px solid #cecece;">
<div class="row" style="border:2px solid #1ecbe1;">

  <div class="core mx-auto">
    <div class="BannerPosition">

      <!--Banner Description-->
      <p class="BannerText"> 
        <div data-highlightword="Anything">
            Anything Anything in Anything
        </div> 
      </p>
            
      <!--Download Badges-->  
      <img class="appleBadge" src="AppleBadge.jpg">                 
      <img class="googleBadge" src="GoogleBadge.jpg">
    
    </div>
  </div>

  //PROBLEM IS HERE
  <div class="col">
    <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap">  
      <img src="VampireCrew.jpg" style="border:2px solid #cecece;">
    </div>  
  </div>  

</div>
```

[image: Full Width]

[image: Minimized Width]

Answer (score 0):

You can control when the image goes underneath the text by column by using Bootstrap’s columns with breakpoints.

I’ve modified your code to have two 12 column wide columns at the start (small screen) and then the columns switch to a 4 and an 8 from medium size displays and up. You can then use Bootstrap’s sizing utilities to adjust the margins if you want, and I added some CSS to adjust the text size from smaller screens to larger screens using Bootstrap’s normal breakpoints.

To keep the image fitting, I applied Bootstrap’s `img-fluid` class.

```css
.orange {
  color: #FD9B42;
}

.banner {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.apple-badge, .google-badge {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width:768px){
  .banner {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
   .banner {
     font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-xs" style="border:2px solid #cecece;">
   <div class="row" style="border:2px solid #1ecbe1;">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-5 mb-md-0">
          <div class="BannerPosition text-center">

            <!--Banner Description-->
            <p class="banner orange">Anything</p>
              <p class="banner">Anything</p>
            <p class="banner">Anything in Anything</p>
            
            <!--Download Badges-->  
            <img class="apple-badge" alt="Apple badge" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50.png?text=Apple">                 
            <img class="google-badge" alt="Google badge" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50.png?text=Google">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
         <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png?text=vampire" alt="Vampires" style="border:2px solid #cecece;">
     </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
```